# Showing elements one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I often see questions like this one and there are multiple solutions. I'm trying to come up with something short that can be reusable. My question is, given the following code, do I need to `clearTimeout()` and where to do it? And also, anything you would improve? How good or bad is this piece of code for performance?
http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/fQX8M/15/

```
var fade1by1 = function ($elms, props) {

    props = props || {};
    props.delay = props.delay || 1; // s
    props.speed = props.speed || 400; // ms
    props.ease = props.ease || 'linear';

    for (var i=0, d=0, l=$elms.length; i<l; i++, d+=props.delay*1000) {
        (function (i, d) {
            // Using `delay()` instead of `setTimeout()`
            // as Alexander suggested
            $elms.eq(i).delay(d).fadeIn(props.speed, props.ease);
        })(i, d);
    }
};
```

Comment: That's quite cool actually. If I was to add more functionality I would add a parameter to set individual fade speed as a replacement for 'slow', and use 'slow' or 200 as the fallback.

Comment: Oh, yeah I will eventually make a plugin out of this but I just want to see if the simplest case could be improved. Then I'll get into customization. Mostly I want to know if it's really necessary to `clearTimout()` in this case...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would only need a clearTimeout() if the timer was running indefinitely. In this case, it only runs for the given number of elements so you don't need a clear. Unless of course you were to add a stop button to stop the next element coming at any point. Also here's a quick version of it with ind_speed (not that you wouldn't have got it yourself, but I just wanted to see it :p http://jsfiddle.net/fQX8M/7/

Comment: I updated it with a few more variables. Do you know how can I track timeouts with devtools or similar? Maybe with breakpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to `window.clearTimeout` since it does not seem like you want to stop the animation. If you are still undecided then what about using [.delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), it clearly uses `window.setTimeout` also.

```
var fade1by1 = function ($elms, speed) {
    speed = speed || 1; // Seconds
    for (var i=0, s=0, l=$elms.length; i<l; i++, s+=speed*1000) {
        $elms.eq(i).delay(s).fadeIn('slow');
    }
};
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H7jWh/).

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but It doesn't work properly as you can see http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/fQX8M/13/

Comment: I just tried with the closure function and it works. See update in question. That reduces the code a bit. So I guess there's not much I can do to make it lighter. I mean is light enough, but I'm worried about performance because I want to implement this at a large scale.

Comment: It worked for me without the closure function. I put a jsfiddle in the answer linking to it.

Comment: Oh man, you're right! Thanks. I'm gonna make a little plugin with this. It should perform fast even for large collections of objects.

Comment: Regarding performance, I think it may be better only to queue one at a time if you have tons of it, but this may be browser-related depending  of the memory footprint of these events.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your approach?

Comment: I think the other answers has already done this. Using the complete animation callback to animate one element at a time. Unfortunately due to traversal limitations I can't see a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you should do this with the fadeIn function's callback.  Something like the following should accomplish all of your goals (substitute in your new params):

```
var customFade = function(parent, speed){
    $(':hidden:first', parent).fadeIn(speed, function(){
        customFade(parent, speed)
    });
}
$('button').click(function(){ customFade($('ul'), 1000); });
```

Comment: Unless of course you want to begin fading while another is still going.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting all the actions at once with increasingly long wait periods, another approach is to bind the show behavior directly to each selected element as a custom event, and include in that bound function a fixed waiting period plus a call to trigger the custom event of the "next" element, if present. To get it started, you just light the fuse of the first element.

So, something like this:

```
var fadeCascade = function fadeCascade(your_selector, props) {
  props = props || {};
  props.delay = props.delay || 1; // s
  props.speed = props.speed || 2000; // ms
  props.ease = props.ease || 'linear';

  $(your_selector)
    .addClass('showme') // Being a little lazy here, but it works
                        // You could work out an inspection by attached event
    .bind('showme', function() { // custom event 
      $(this)
        .delay( props.delay * 1000 )
        .fadeIn(props.speed, props.ease, function() {
          $(this).nextAll('.showme:first').trigger('showme'); // jqueryish recursion
      });
    }).hide() // or just hide in initial css
  .first().trigger('showme'); // set the dominoes falling
};
```

And to trigger the reveal:

```
fadeCascade('div.bar');​
```

If you're concerned about hygiene, you could unbind events and remove classes as you go.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/EKx6s/1/

Update: Added delay, thanks @Alexander.

Comment: Is it just me or you are missing the delay there?